# Add additional text on TextChange asp.net

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

Reason i'd like to add additional text is because, for whatever reason when i try to login and  it wants me to add "@domain.local".

Is it possible to add that automatically? I tried converting it to a template and used UserName_TextChanged but it didn't like what i was trying to do.

[image: Using this]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information on the web.config you are using Forms Authentication with an LDAP provider.  I am going to make the assumption that you are using the ASP.NET Login control on your page.

In order to handle the appending of @domain.local to a user name prior to login you should handle the LoggingIn Event from the control with something similar to the following:

```
    void OnLoggingIn(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Login1.UserName.IndexOf("@domain.local", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
        {
            Login1.UserName += "@domain.local";
        }
    }
```

Of course you probably need a more precise process to determine the proper way to handle the user name.

You can find more information about the login control and its events here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggingin(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you mean "authentication provider"?

Comment: ASP.NET supports multiple authentication providers.  You can use Forms Authentication, Federated Authentication, LDAP Authentication, etc.  Basically what system are you using to authenticate your users.  You should be able to find this information in your Web.Config <authentication> section.

Comment: Oh okay, im using LDAP. Here is the [webconfig code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztj85x6fmbjjalj/webconfig.txt).

Comment: I updated the answer to show a way to handle your requirement using the LogginIn event for the login control.

Comment: Thanks bunch, i was a little lost until i clicked on that link.